# jhbuild build getting the wrong meson version that is not installed on my system

Tags: gtk, gtk3, meson-build, jhbuild

When I run: `jhbuild build gtk+-3`

I get:

> Meson encountered an error in file meson.build, line 1, column 0:
>
> Meson version is 0.44.1 but project requires >= 0.45.0.

But when I run: `~/.local/bin/meson --version` I get:

```
0.46.1
```

So my version is height enough.

So what is going on? Where is it getting this 0.44.1?

I did try to do `find / -name meson` the only I found was the `0.46.1 version`.

I also tried with: `alias meson="~/.local/bin/meson"`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `meson` binary is not the one used. Try `jhbuild shell`, then `which meson` to check which meson is used. `meson --version` will probably tell you it's 0.44.1.

Comment: I did a `find` to see if it was installed anywhere else I also used `alias meson=...` to the newest version. Something is broken with jhbuild... Or is there a way to force it to use the newest version?

Comment: I found another meson on my system: `~/jhbuild/install/bin/meson` version `0.46.1` so jhbuild is not using it's own meson?

Comment: Then try `jhbuild run which meson` and `jhbuild run meson --version`.

Comment: The `alias` might of been conflicting with the jhbuild because now when I check the version I get 0.44... For some weird reason the shell doesn't work. Maybe ZSH is causing some other conflict. Anyways.